# Add vertical line to ListLogPlot

Tags: plotting

When I add a Line or a point to a `ListLogPlot` using for example `Show[plot,Graphics[Line[{{0,0.1},{100,0.1}}]` it does not appear where I put it but instead `-Exp[#]&` gets applied to the y coordinates. So in this case the line appears around 0.905. How do I add graphics at the actual points I want to add them?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the GridLines option of ListLogPlot instead? For example, `GridLines->{{}, {.1}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
plot = ListLogPlot[Table[PartitionsQ[n], {n, 50}], 
  Joined -> True];
```

On a log plot the y coordinate cannot be zero. Whatever y value is intended, you need to take its log. For either vertical or horizontal lines, [`InfiniteLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html) (introduced in version 10) is the easiest way to span the full plot.

```
Show[plot, 
  Graphics[{Red, InfiniteLine[{{1, Log[20]}, {10, Log[20]}}],
   Green, InfiniteLine[{{30, 1}, {30, 10}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I already edited the question to point out that 0.1 would be a better example I can also edit it in the main text if preferred. Note that the point stands for any number greater than 0. It is in my opinion a crazy choice of MMA to implement things this way and I would like a real work around, rather than applying Log to everything I might ever add to a plot. Note that if for example I want to add points at coordinates I picked (using `.`) I would have to first apply Log to them. That would be a major inconvenience.

Comment: To add points use `Point[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ points]`